# Replacing inner div content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'd like to replace the following inner div content:

```
<div class="price"><span class="unit">$</span>37</div>
```

with this:

```
<del>$37</del> $19
```

The $37 gets striked through and the new price is displayed next to it.  The above `<div>` is generated dynamically.

I have tried the following but it isn't doing anything:

```
$( "div.price" ).replaceWith("<del>$37</del> $19");
```

I'm trying this in jquery but is there a way to do it in angular?  I guess the issue with angular is that I can't add directives to the above code.

Comment: all those values (i.e., `37`) are hard-coded? you are not binding them to any variables you can access in your controller?

Comment: $( "div.price" ).html("<del>$37</del> $19")

Comment: That is correct.  You set those values up on the back end in a Wordpress theme element.

Comment: @VladuIonut: Not working - http://plnkr.co/edit/HoDQUsoUlL51M4THlQDN?p=preview

Comment: You need to make the sure the DOM has loaded before running the script. So put the script beneath the body, or wrap it in a window.load

Comment: Hope you have jQuery included!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

run the code on document ready

```
// Code goes here
$(function(){
$( "div.price" ).html("<del>$37</del> $19") 
});
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to be doing anything: http://plnkr.co/edit/5sWzcvDALUmPHdSKC7xH?p=preview

Comment: $(function(){ }); is same with $( document ).ready(function() { });  http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/